# Recipe for a 2m x 1m concrete working plane

Tags: concrete, furniture, desk

I'd like to create working plane from concrete to be put on a support and be used as desk. The dimension should be 1m x 2m and the thickness will depend on recommendations. It should support 150 kg.

I plan to mold the concrete in a wooden form and flatten it before leaving it to set and dry (28 days).

I'd like to use glass fiber as enforcement to lower costs and weight. I assume that it's fine to use fiber glass isolation mats and somehow cut them into pieces and mix them with the liquid concrete before molding. I'm uncertain about the technique for the mixture (how to avoid clumps of fibers) and the amount of fiber per volume.

Does the plan with the reinforcement work (if yes, how to mix in the fibers) or do I need to use steel? What thickness should I use?

A place to dry, the construction for the form and health protection (I'll use a full mask for cutting the glass fiber) is not an issue nor is the weight of the resulting plane as long as it's below 100kg.

Comment: Flagging to move to arts and crafts, since this isn't really about home improvement

Comment: 1m x 2m x 4" could be around 600lb (250kq +/-)  To make it thinner, you need high PSI concrete, reinforcement of which their are many types, additives to help with setting time, strength, consistency, etc.  There is a reason concrete counter-top companies are completely different from normal "concrete" contractors.  I would recommend a specific question if you are looking for help.

Comment: This is the type of fiberglass you would use with poured concrete: http://www.fibreglast.com/product/837/Fillers?gclid=CL7IuM-Z6tACFZu6wAodNKoOQA  if ends show on the finished surface you can burn them off with a torch.

Comment: @mmathis I don't think users on Arts and Crafts would have the necessary skills to answer this.